# Relative Spaces in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-spaces

I usually have a 4x3 grid for spaces. Each row is dedicated to a different subject/project. Does anyone know a way to move to different column of the current row? So if I pressed control + 1 it would move to column 1 of whatever row I was current in.

Answer (score 1):

control-up, control-down will move you to the space above and below you.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure how to switch between Spaces in *System Preferences » Exposé & Spaces » Spaces*:
[image]

The highlighted popup menu allows you to configure the shortcuts for moving to adjacent spaces by pressing a combination of *{Command, Control, Option}* and the arrow keys (left, right, up down, depending on your desired direction).

[image]

Keep your desired modifiers (Command, Control, Option, Shift) pressed while the popup menu is open to get additional variants (pictured: while pressing *Shift* and *Command*).

[image]

---

You cannot jump to "column 1 of the current row" though. Only absolute movements (to space 1) and relative movements (to the space to the left of the current one) are possible, no "hybrid".

Answer (score 0):

[HyperSpaces](https://hyperspacesapp.com) appears to offer a "Switch to this space" hotkey for each defined space

[image]

and a "Back to the previous space" key, among lots of others.  Plus the menu bar icon opens a clickable spaces map.  And my favorite option: custom background for each space.